# Django Form- Password Validation

Tags: python, django, forms, web, input

I am new to Django just started learning it yesterday.
I am trying to create a register form. I know there is inbuilt django register system.
But i am trying to it myself.
This is my Views.py-

```py
def register(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, 'users.html', {})
    else:
        if (request.method=='POST'):
            form=Register(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return render(request,'home.html',{})

        else:
            return render(request,'register.html', {})
```

Template-

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required><br>
    <input type="email" name="username" placeholder="Email" required><br>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" required><br>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="cpassword" required><br>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female<br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

form.py

```py
class Register(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Users
        fields = ["username", "email", "password","gender"]
```

But since there is no confirm password field in form.py. It does not past form.is_valid() statement.
I know this may be a stupid. But just can't find a way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

to check password validation, you can use this algorithm in views.py

```
    password = request.POST["password"]
    confirmation = request.POST["cpassword"]
    if password != confirmation:
        return render(request, "register.html", {
            "message": "Passwords must match."
        })
```

and in the template set form action like this

```
    form action="{% url 'register' %}"
```

You should either use Django-forms by using forms.py or manual form like you did in the template.
For using Django forms I recommend you to read the docs. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/

Comment: You should also take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/validation/ and how to override clean(). You probable need to remove cpassword from the cleaned_data.

Comment: i looked at the article and i was able find self.add_error('cpassword',msg) to remove a field but still it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

## Extend Django's `User` model to add your own fieds

You can read [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) on how to do this.

Basically:

```py
# models.py

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class MyUser(models.Model):
    GENDERS = [("F", "female"), ("M", "male")]
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDERS, default="F")
```

## Forms are for data validation

You have two models that are now linked together : `User` and `MyUser`.

You should validate each data against the model that will store it.
This simply means you need two forms:

```py
# forms.py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from myapp.models import MyUser


class UserRegister(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["username", "email", "password"]


class MyUserRegister(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ["gender"]
```

and nothing more here, if you are using Django's `ModelForm` let it do its thing.

## Views use Forms and feed them data

So the work has to be done on the view.

Here's an example of how to do it:

```py
# views.py

from django.shortcuts import render
from myapp.forms import MyUserRegister, UserRegister


def register(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, 'users.html', {})
    else:
        if (request.method == 'POST'):
            user_form = UserRegister(request.POST)
            myuser_form = MyUserRegister(request.POST)
            if user_form.is_valid() and myuser_form.is_valid():
                user_form.save()
                # Now that the User is saved, associate it to the MyUser object before saving
                myuser_form.instance.user = user_form.instance
                myuser_form.save()
                return render(request,'home.html',{})

        else:
            return render(request,'register.html', {})
```

#### Side note

I changed your template to have "M" and "F" as choices to match my model:

```html
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required><br>
    <input type="email" name="username" placeholder="Email" required><br>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" required><br>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="cpassword" required><br>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="M">Male
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="F">Female<br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Hope this clarifies a bit your questions.